# Is there any jQuery custom scrollbar that work with isotope.js?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, jquery-isotope

I want to implement custom scrollbar in isotope, I have used slickcustomscrollbar plugin, however there is problem in implementing with isotope.

Is there any custom scrollbar that work fine with isotope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your isotope container into a new div with fixed height and that should do the trick with with any scroller plugin. Init the scrollbar for the created wrapper.